# Why / when would it be appropriate to override ToString?

Tags: c#, overriding

I'm studying C# and I wonder what the point and benefit of overriding `ToString` might be, as shown in the example below.

Could this be done in some simpler way, using a common method without the override?

```
public string GetToStringItemsHeadings
{
    get { return string.Format("{0,-20} {1, -20}", "Office Email", "Private Email"); }
}


public override string ToString()
{
    string strOut = string.Format("{0,-20} {1, -20}", m_work, m_personal);
    return strOut;
}
```

Comment: Depends if you actually want to use it to display the object in the UI anywhere, else it's usually just for debugging - you'll see the ToString output in VS's watch window. (But you can also achieve that with attributes on the class.) Given you've got headings and output it looks like this program is using it to dump the object out using `Console.WriteLine(obj.GetToStringItemsHeadings); Console.WriteLine(obj);` or similar.

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. Can it be done differently? Yes. But why do you *want* to do it differently.

Comment: I would really skip `GetToString` in the property name... Then you'd get for example `Console.WriteLine(obj.ItemHeadings)`

Comment: and change the ItemHeadings property to be static as it doesn't need any "this".

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906828/oo-design-advice-tostring

Answer (score 127, accepted):

- Do you need to override `ToString`? **No.**
- Can you get a string representation of your object in another way? **Yes.**

But by using `ToString` you are using a method that is common to *all objects* and thus other classes know about this method. For instance, whenever the .NET framework wants to convert an object to a string representation, `ToString` is a prime candidate (there are others, if you want to provide more elaborate formatting options).

Concretely,

```
Console.WriteLine(yourObject);
```

would invoke `yourObject.ToString()`.

Comment: Yes. Also this is very useful in MVC or ASP.Net development where `@yourObject` and `<%=yourObject%>` are going to be "ToString-ed".

Comment: Also when populating a combobox, ToString is the default call to get the item text

Comment: Beware such practice.
True story: a student overrode ToString with a method that besides returning a string, changed the data. He was debugging the program but while the program was standing at a breakpoint the value kept changing. Apparently - each time he checked the value ToString was executed - so the value changed even though the program wasn't running.

Comment: @JNF What is “such practice”? `ToString` shouldn’t actually change the state of an object. But this isn’t what I advocated.

Comment: @Konrad You said the thing about `ToString` is that everyone knows it - that has a plus and a minus.

Comment: @JNF I don’t understand the point, sorry. Code can always be abused, the defence against this surely isn’t using obscure coding practices because well-known ones will be abused.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The point is - be careful when overriding system functions :)

Comment: @JNF I don’t accept that. `ToString` is *meant* to be overridden. Period. Putting a caveat on this statement is not productive. If you do it wrong – your own fault. In fact, your student violated point 4 in the official list of guidelines for overriding `ToString` that was posted in David Anderson’s answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No argument :) just a funny anecdote

Comment: @JNF If a student does something as silly as putting a meaningful state change in a getter, they just need to learn from the experience. After all, they're a student and its better that they learn from their blunders now instead of later when it actually matters…

Comment: @JNF `ToString` was indended from the start to be overridden to display an objects state, which is why it lives on the base object `System.Object`. What the student did is just bad programming (I can't call it bad practice, because it's not practice at all to put behavior in `ToString` that changes the object's state. Hopefully this clears up some confusion.

Answer (score 134):

I'm just going to give you the answer straight from the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines/Krzysztof-Cwalina/e/9780321545619?itm=2&usri=framework%20design%20guidelines) from the .NET Development Series.

**AVOID** throwing exceptions from `ToString`

**CONSIDER** returning a unique string associated with the instance.

**CONSIDER** having the output of `ToString` be a valid input for any parsing methods on this type.

**DO** ensure that `ToString` has no observable side effects.

**DO** report security-sensitive information through an override of `ToString` only after demanding an appropriate permission. If the permission demand fails, return a string excluding security-sensitive information.

The `Object.ToString` method is intended to be used for general display and debugging purposes. The default implementation simply provides the object type name. The default implementation is not very useful, and it is recommended that the method be overridden.

**DO** override `ToString` whenever an interesting human-readable string can be returned. The default implementation is not very useful, and a custom implementation can almost always provide more value.

**DO** prefer a friendly name over a unique but not readable ID.

It is also worth mentioning as Chris Sells also explains in the guidelines that `ToString` is often dangerous for user interfaces. Generally my rule of thumb is to expose a property that would be used for binding information to the UI, and leave the `ToString` override for displaying diagnostic information to the developer. You can also decorate your type with `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` as well.

**DO** try to keep the string returned from `ToString` short. The debugger uses `ToString` to get a textual representation of an object to be shown to the developer. If the string is longer than the debugger can display, the debugging experience is hindered.

**DO** string formatting based on the current thread culture when returning culture-dependent information.

**DO** provide overload `ToString(string format)`, or implement `IFormattable`, if the string return from `ToString` is culture-sensitive or there are various ways to format the string. For example, `DateTime` provides the overload and implements `IFormattable`.

**DO NOT** return an empty string or null from `ToString`

I swear by these guidelines, and you should  to. I can't tell you how my code has improved just by this one guideline for `ToString`. The same thing goes for things like `IEquatable(Of T)` and `IComparable(Of T)`. These things make your code very functional, and you won't regret taking the extra time to implement any of it.

Personally, I've never really used `ToString` *much* for user interfaces, I have always exposed a property or method of some-sort. The majority of the time you should use `ToString` for debugging and developer purposes. Use it to display important diagnostic information.

Comment: Nice answer, are these the guidelines to which you refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx ?

Comment: @Jodrell I believe it's taken from [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613)

Comment: Jim is right, these are from Framework Design Guidelines, which are the guidelines MSFT uses to develop their managed API's. I highly recommend purchasing the book because it will change the way you engineer your software and produce high quality code.

Comment: I think that I like this one the best. 
DO NOT return an empty string or null from ToString

Answer (score 39):

Overriding `ToString()` allows you to give a useful human-readable string representation of a class.

This means that the output can reveal useful information about your class. For example, if you had a Person class you might choose to have the `ToString()` output the person's id, their firstname, their lastname etc. This is extremely useful when debugging or logging.

With regard to your example - it is difficult to tell if your override is useful without knowing what this class is - but the implementation itself is ok.

Answer (score 13):

**It's always appropriate but carefully consider the intentions behind what you're displaying**

A better question would be to ask:

> Why would one override ToString()?

ToString() is the window into an object's state. Emphasis on **state** as a requirement. Strongly OOP languages like Java/C# abuse the OOP model by encapsulating everything in a class. Imagine you are coding in a language that doesn't follow the strong OOP model; consider whether you'd use a class or a function. If you would use it as a function (ie verb, action) and internal state is only maintained temporarily between input/output, ToString() won't add value.

Like others have mentioned, it's important to consider **what** you output with ToString() because it could be used by the debugger or other systems.

I like to imagine the ToString method as the --help parameter of an object. It should be short, readable, obvious, and easy to display. It should display what the object *is* not what it *does*. With all that in mind let's consider...

**Use Case - Parsing a TCP packet:**

Not an application-level-only network capture but something with more meat like a pcap capture.

You want to overload ToString() for just the TCP layer so you can print data to the console. What would it include? You could go crazy and parse all of the TCP details (ie TCP is complex)...

Which includes the:

- Source Port
- Destination Port
- Sequence Number
- Acknowledgment number
- Data offset
- Flags
- Window Offset
- Checksum
- Urgent Pointer
- Options (I'm not *even* going to go there)

But would you want to receive all that junk if you were calling TCP.ToString() on 100 packets? Of course not, it would be information overload. The easy and obvious choice is also the most sensible...

**Expose what people would expect to see:**

- Source Port
- Destination Port

I prefer a sensible output that's easy for humans to parse but [YMMV](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=YMMV).

```
TCP:[destination:000, source:000]
```

Nothing complex, the output isn't for machines to parse (ie unless people are abusing your code), the intended purpose is for human readability.

But what about all the rest of that juicy info I talked about before, isn't that useful too? I'll get to that but first...

---

**ToString() one of the most valuable and underused methods of all time**

For two reasons:

1. People don't understand what ToString() is for
2. The base 'Object' class is missing another, equally important, string method.

**Reason 1 - Don't abuse the usefulness of ToString():**

A lot of people use ToString() to pull a simple string representation of an object. The C# manual even states:

> ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework. It converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for display.

**Display,** not further processing. That doesn't mean, take my nice string representation of the TCP packet above and pull the source port using a regex ::cringe::.

The **right** way to do things is, call ToString() directly on the SourcePort property (which BTW is a ushort so ToString() should already be available).

If you need something more robust to package the state of a complex object for machine parsing you'll be better off using a structured serialization strategy.

Fortunately, such strategies are very common:

- ISerializable (C#)
- Pickle (Python)
- JSON (Javascript or any language that implements it)
- SOAP
- etc...

*Note: Unless you're using PHP because, herp-derp, there's a function for that ::snicker::*

**Reason 2 - ToString() is not enough:**

I have yet to see a language that implements this at the core but I have seen and used variations of this approach in the wild.

Some of which include:

- ToVerboseString()
- ToString(verbose=true)

Basically, that hairy mess of a TCP Packet's state *should* be described for human readability. To avoid 'beating a dead horse' talking about TCP I'll 'point a finger' at the #1 case where I think ToString() and ToVerboseString() are underutilized...

**Use Case - Arrays:**

If you primarily use one language, you're probably comfortable with that language's approach. For people like me who jump between different languages, the number of varied approaches can be irritating.

*Ie, the number of times this has irritated me is greater than the sum of all of the fingers of every Hindu god combined.*

There are [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970738/convert-system-array-to-string) cases where languages use common [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605773/php-array-to-string-equivalent) and a [few](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp) that [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java) it [right](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array.tostring). Some require wheel re-inventing, some do a shallow dump, others do a deep dump, none of them work the way I'd like them to...

What I'm asking for is a very simple approach:

```
print(array.ToString());
```

> Outputs: 'Array[x]' or 'Array[x][y]'

Where x is the number of items in the first dimension and y is the number of items in the second dimension or some value that indicates that the 2nd dimension is jagged (min/max range maybe?).

And:

```
print(array.ToVerboseString());
```

> Outputs the whole she-bang in pretty-print because I appreciate pretty things.

Hopefully, this sheds some light on a topic that has irked me for a long time. At the very least I sprinkled a little troll-bait for the PHPers to downvote this answer.

Comment: You wrote, "I have yet to see a language that implements this at the core". It seems to me that Python comes pretty close to this; e.g. printing an array gives all its data concisely. That's one thing I miss in C#/Java, though I do like their rigorousness. And when you need to go a tad beyond ToString(), it would be nice to have something like Python's list comprehension syntax; I guess string.Join() is similar, though less flexible.

Comment: @JCoombs I don't disagree, comprehensions are great. Traversing data structures in Python via comprehensions makes life a lot easier but that approach still requires intimate knowledge of the object's internal structure. Something that's not always obvious with classes that have been imported from an external library. It's good practice for the library authors to override ToString() and provide a useful human-readable representation but it would also be good to have a general dump method that outputs the object's structure in a general structured human readable format (ex JSON).

Comment: Excellent point. So instead of showing nothing more than basically a typeof, it might auto-serialize to something like JSON. (So far, I've only seen .NET objects serialized to XML, but I'm new to .NET) But then the danger might be the temptation to treat ToString() as machine-readable? (E.g. expect to be able to deserialize it.)

Comment: @JCoombs Yep, on a functional level JSON and XML serve the same purpose. Plenty of people do use ToString as a machine-readable output; whether or not that's bad is debatable. My biggest beef is -- often times -- it's a pain to output the state of an object in a human-readable format. ToString() implementation is often under-utilized and reading an object's state outside of debugger watch lists is a pain. Serialized representations are good as a backup for displaying an objects whole state but better implementations of ToString are the best option.

Comment: If `ToString()` is meant for debugging, then why is it the only way to extract the entire text from a StringBuilder - an important function?

Answer (score 9):

It's about good practise as much as anything, really.

`ToString()` is used in many places to return a string representation of an object, generally for consumption by a human.  Often that same string can be used to rehydrate the object (think of `int` or `DateTime` for example), but that's not always a given (a tree for example, might have a useful string representation which simply displays a Count, but clearly you can't use that to rebuild it).

In particular the debugger will use this to display the variable in the watch windows, immediate windows etc, therefore `ToString` is actually invaluable for debugging.

In general, also, such a type will often have an explicit member that returns a string as well.  For example a Lat/Long pair might have `ToDecimalDegrees` which returns `"-10, 50"` for example, but it might also have `ToDegreesMinutesSeconds`, since that is another format for a Lat/Long pair.  That same type might then also override `ToString` with one of those to provide a 'default' for things like debugging, or even potentially for things like rendering web pages (for example, the `@` construct in Razor writes the `ToString()` result of a non-string expression to the output stream).

Answer (score 6):

`object.ToString()` converts an object to its string representation. If you want to change what is returned when a user calls `ToString()` on a class you have created then you would need to override `ToString()` in that class.

Answer (score 6):

While I think the most useful information has already been provided, I shall add my two cents:

- `ToString()` is meant to be overridden. Its default implementation returns the type name which, while maybe useful at times (particularly when working with a lot of objects), doesn't suffice in the big majority of times.
- Remember that, for debugging purposes, you can rely on `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`. You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices.aspx).
- As a rule, on POCOs you can always override `ToString()`. POCOs are a structured representation of data, which usually can become a string.
- Design ToString to be a textual representation of your object. Maybe its main fields and data, maybe a description of how many items are in the collection, etc.
- Always try to fit that string into a single line and have only essential information. If you have a `Person` class with Name, Address, Number etc. properties, return only the main data (Name some ID number).
- Be careful not to override a good implementation of `ToString()`. Some framework classes already implement `ToString()`. Overriding that default implementation is a bad thing: people will expect a certain result from `ToString()` and get another.

Don't be really afraid of using `ToString()`. The only thing I'd be careful about is returning sensitive information. Other than that, the risk is minimal. Sure, as some have pointed out, other classes will use your ToString whenever reaching for information. But heck, **when does returning the type name will be considered better than getting some actual information?**

Answer (score 5):

If you don't override `ToString` then you get your base classes implementation which, for `Object` is just the short type name of the class.

If you want some other, more meaningful or useful implementation of `ToString` then  override it.

---

This can be useful when using a list of your type as the datasource for a `ListBox` as the `ToString` will be automatically displayed.

Another situtation occurs when you want to pass your type to `String.Format` which invokes `ToString` to get a representation of your type.

Answer (score 4):

Something no one else has mentioned yet: By overriding `ToString()`, you can also consider implementing `IFormattable` so you can do the following:

```
 public override ToString() {
   return string.Format("{0,-20} {1, -20}", m_work, m_personal);
 }

 public ToString(string formatter) {
   string formattedEmail = this.ToString();
   switch (formatter.ToLower()) {
     case "w":
       formattedEmail = m_Work;
       break;
     case "p":
       formattedEmail = m_Personal;
       break;
     case "hw":
       formattedEmail = string.Format("mailto:{0}", m_Work);
       break;
   }
   return formattedEmail;
}
```

Which can be useful.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a framwork class providing that method to override? The only related stuff I'm aware of in the framework is the `IFormattible` interface.

Comment: @tm1 Any object that inherits from `System.Object` will have an overridable `ToString()` method, but you're right that the formatter method shouldn't be `override` and should really reference the `IFormattible` interface for complete conformity.

Comment: Almost - `IFormattable` takes an `IFormatProvider` parameter. Thanks to edit your post, though.

Comment: Indeed, it has two methods, the value I was expressing was in the one shown ;)

Answer (score 3):

One benefit of overriding ToString() is Resharper's tooling support: Alt + Ins -> "Formatting members" and it writes the ToString() for you.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it makes it easier to read values of custom classes in the debugger watch window.  If I know exactly what I want to see in the watch window, when I override ToString with that information, then I see it.

Answer (score 1):

When defining structs (effectively user-primitives) I find it's good practice to have matching `ToString`, and `Parse` and `TryParse` methods, particularly for XML serialization. In this case you will be converting the entire state to a string, so that it can be read from later.

Classes however are more compound structures that will usually be too complex for using `ToString` and `Parse`. Their `ToString` methods, instead of saving the entire state, can be a simple description that helps you identify their state, like a unique identifier like a name or ID, or maybe a quantity for a list.

Also, as Robbie said, overriding `ToString` allows you to call `ToString` on a reference as basic as type `object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that when you have an object with not intuitive meaning of string representation, like person. So if you need for example to print this person you can use this override for preparing it's format.

Answer (score 1):

The `Object.ToString` method should be used for debugging purposes only. The default implementation shows the object type name which is not very useful. Consider to override this method to provide better information for diagnostics and debugging. Please consider that logging infrastructures often use the ToString method as well and so you will find these text fragments in your log files.

**Do not** return localized text resources within the `Object.ToString` method. The reason is that the ToString method should always return something that the developer can understand. The developer might not speak all languages which the application supports.

**Implement** the `IFormattable` interface when you want to return a user-friendly localized text. This interface defines a ToString overload with the parameters `format` and `formatProvider`. The formatProvider helps you to format the text in a culture aware way.

See also: [Object.ToString and IFormattable](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Object.ToString-and-IFormattable)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler depends on how your property is going to be used. If you just need to format the string one time then it does not make that much sense overriding it.

However, It appears that you are overriding the ToString method to not return the normal string data for your property , but to perform a standard formatting pattern. Since you are using string.format with padding.

Because you said you are learning, the exercise appears to also hit on core principles in object oriented programming relating to encapsulation and code re-use.

The string.format taking the arguments you have set for padding ensures that the property will be formatted the same way each time for any code that calls it. As well, going forward you only have to change it in one place instead of many.

Great question and also some great answers!

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to override the ToString method on entity classes as it helps quickly identify issues in testing especially when an assertion fails the test console will invoke the ToString method on the object.

But in agreement with what has been said before it's to give a human readable representation of the object in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with the Framework Guidelines referred to in other answers.
However, I'd like to emphasize the display and debugging purposes.

Be careful about how you use `ToString` in your code. Your code shouldn't rely on the string representation of an object. If it does, you should absolutely provide the respective `Parse` methods.

Since `ToString` can be used everywhere, it can be a maintainability pain point if you want to change the string representation of an object at a later point in time. You cannot just examine the call hierarchy in this case to study whether some code will break.