# Is it ok to override ToString() method in this case

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, tostring

I need to be able to retrieve the string version of the object.

For ex: Below `SearchCriteria` should provide  "`Search Parameters: FromDate:{0}, ToDate {1}, ..`"

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
  public string FromDate {get;set;}
  public string ToDate {get;set;}
  public string FromAge {get;set;}
  public string ToAge {get;set;}

  //other 10 properties
}
```

But from other threads I read, it is not recommended to use ToString() for long strings due to performance problems. I would like to know if it is ok to use it this way or shall I consider using private method.

**EDIT**

This string representation is used in the business logic NOT for debugging purpose.

Comment: That's what toString is for, it will get evaluated when it is called so no performance problems

Comment: If you don't have a dozen unrelated things asking these objects for their string representation, then it should not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx): 
"Returns a string that represents the current object."

If you want to create a string which is a representation of the object, that is the place.

So - yes!

## EDIT:

"This string representation is used in the business logic NOT for debugging purpose."

The string representation of `int` is also used for business logic. The question is if that string representation is specific for that business logic, or is it just a general representation of that object, which you use in business logic.

If it specific for that specific business logic, the generation of the string suppose to be part of that business logic.

If not, but there are many optional string representations for that object, you may want to implement [`IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx), which defines a `ToString` method which gets an `IFormatProvider` and format string as parameters.

Otherwise, the regular `ToString` is your friend.

Comment: Don't think that it is a good idea using ToString() for business logic.  ToString() is made for getting a string representation for an object (e.g. for displaying that information to the user).

But business logic should not rely on what is returned by ToString(). Separate presentation and business logic!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely override `ToString()` to return whatever is most meaningful information.

I would think that a string that's too long could cause some problems and be less useful. For example, longer strings won't have room in the Watch Window and could have other considerations. So I would look for a way to shorten the output and still be meaningful.

But by all means, override `ToString()` so your own types return meaningful information.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Of course it's 'ok'. In the sense that pissing your pants is 'ok'. For 5 seconds it's warm and the relieve feels great. But then you need clean pants.

It's not ok in the sense that it closely resembles loose-typing. 'ToString's implementation is so wildly different in objects in the framework in general and more specific in the objects created by all the different tool and business developers.

My 2 cents: Give it a descriptive name, because odds are, later you'll needs yet another string representation of the same object. It's more readable if you develop an API and it's more readable for you later on.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than worrying about performance of `ToString()`, I would look at readability and expected behavior.

I have always used `ToString()` to implement the user-friendly display of an object. That is, how would I always want the object to be displayed, even if the caller doesn't know anything about my class (say, writing to a log or on the console, or even displaying in the UI).

For action-specific implementations, I would implement another function, but follow a similar naming pattern. Say, `ToFormattedQueryString()`.

Here's a good discussion on rules of thumb for `ToString()`: [Why / when would it be appropriate to override ToString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278049/why-when-would-it-be-appropriate-to-override-tostring).

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about performance, you can add field to your class to store the string, and then add code to `set` for each property to re-compute your string at the point. Then `ToString()` can be efficient.

Personally, I think the extra code and the overhead in recomputing that string all the time (which may never be used) will not justify the change.

What I will advise, is that since performance is your primary concern here, go ahead and write the code the way *you* want to write, in the way that you feel is the more clear and the most maintainable, then let a **profiler** tool tell you where you need to go back and optimize.