# Casting an object inside join statement

Tags: c#, linq, casting

Want to concatenate all the items that are selected in my ListBox (SelectedItems). The list box is using a class (RegionModel) as a datadource.

I have this going in foreach loop, but I'd like to put this into a single line, if possible. What I have doesn't break, but it doesn't print, just the class name that the item represents.

```
namespace ProLimb.Models
{
    public class RegionModel
    {
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    //TRYING TO GET TO WORK
    Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<object>());
}
```

I figure I need to cast it, it doesn't seem to work.

The final output should look like: "North; East; South; West", but instead it comes out: ProLimb.Forms.RegionModel

Comment: the casting is not the problem. You need to override the `ToString` method in your `class RegionModel` this will determine what you will see as the output. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33166948/5174469) might help

Comment: which of the properties is supposed to hold the information  "North; East; South; West" ? `Continent` ? or `Country` ?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two answers can solve your problem stated by Mong Zhu and [Ehsan Sajjad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57752530/2122217)

all you need to show us is which property you want to contain/display `Continent` or `Country`

or my answer which is reflection if you dont want to overwrite your `ToString()`

`PropertyYouWantToShow` is either `Continent` or `Country`

```
Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<object>()
                .Select(c => c.GetType()
                              .GetProperty("PropertyYouWantToShow") //will get property
                              .GetValue(c))); //will get values listed on PropertyYouWantToShow
```

or you could cast it in your `select`[as per Richard Barker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57752461/2122217) but still add `OfType<object>`

```
Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<object>()
                .Select(c => ((RegionModel)c).PropertyYouWantToShow)); // either Country or Continent
```

or you could directly cast it in your `OfType`

```
Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<RegionModel>()
                .Select(c => c.PropertyYouWantToShow));
```

Comment: My apologies guy; it's late; delete!!

Comment: the `.ToString()` call is superfluous here. `string.Join` will call it automatically on each item of the collection

Comment: @MongZhu Oh, sorry, force of habit, will edit answer, thanks!

Comment: Why `.ToList()`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, sorry, also force of habit/practice to know if variable/function return/linq created is List just looking at the end.

Comment: At the cost of allocating a list? `string.Join` takes an `IEnumerable<T>` which is what `Enumerable.Select<TSource>(...)` returns.

Comment: @PauloMorgado thanks for the input, will edit answer

Comment: Thanks, everyone. This, along with @RichardBarker's answer worked! I did need to add the "OfType<object>()"

Comment: var regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<object>()
    .Select(c => ((RegionModel)c).Continent));

Comment: You should be able to use `ofType<RegiomModel>` and remove the cast in the select, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `ToString()` method for your class and then just call it in a linq select:

```
public class RegionModel
{
    public string Continent { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
       return $"{Country},{Continent}";
    }
}
```

and then :

```
string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems);
```

The above is just an example to show how `ToString()` can be used here but you might need to return either only `Country` or `Continent` as per your need.

Comment: Problem being that now, anywhere you ambiguously convert RegionModel to a string, say for instance logs, you'll see the results of the to string. That is very likely is breaking change to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to `Cast()` your entities. As far as I understand, SelectedItems is not a generic collection but still implements `IEnumerable`. If you want to use LINQ on it, you have two options:

- If you know for sure collection only has items of certain type, you have to use `Cast<T>()` on a collection to transform `IEnumerable` into `IEnumerable<T>`.
- If you're not sure what type of items are present in the collection, and only want to deal with items of a particular type ignoring all the others, you need to use `OfType<T>()`, yielding `IEnumerable<T>` that only contains objects of the specified type.

Try this:

```
Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.Cast<RegionModel>().Select(x => x.Country));
```

This would also work:

```
Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<RegionModel>().Select(x => x.Country));
```

Whether the latter is more preferable in your scenario is up to your programming style, but I recommend the first version. That way if the collection contains items of unexpected type, you won't ignore it and fail fast, which is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
namespace ProLimb.Models
{
    public class RegionModel
    {
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    //TRYING TO GET TO WORK
    Regions = string.Join("; ", lstRegions.SelectedItems.OfType<RegionModel>().Select(x => x.Continent));
}
```

You were trying to concatenate your objects but they aren't string, so you have to ask for the property you need.