# Return values from class constructor calling

Tags: c#, tostring

```
[Fact]
public void On_the_hour()
{
    var sut = new Clock(8, 0);
    Assert.Equal("08:00", sut.ToString());
}
```

I want to create class Clock with contructor which has parameters hours and minutes.

After calling it in another class(code above) how to return values?
So, when i call Clock.ToString() i want to receive "hours:minutes"

```
public class Clock
{
    public int Hours;
    public int Minutes;

    public Clock(int hours, int minutes)
    {
        Hours = hours;
        Minutes = minutes;
    }
}
```

Comment: [The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) provides

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to override ToString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166889/why-do-i-need-to-override-tostring) and [Override .ToString method c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200427/override-tostring-method-c-sharp/18200481)

Answer (score 1):

You have to `override` the `ToString()` method with desired *implementation*.

For padding with `zeros` you can use `$"{Hours:00}:{Minutes:00}"`.

```
public class Clock
{
   public int Hours;
   public int Minutes;

   public Clock(int hours, int minutes)
   {
       Hours = hours;
       Minutes = minutes;
   }
    
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return $"{Hours:00}:{Minutes:00}";
   }
}
```

Comment: Please use format strings instead, `$"{Hours:00}:{Minutes:00}"`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes, good point, shortest version.