# How to write temporary results in a tostring method to give an overview afterwards

Tags: c#, tostring

I'm quite new to programming and i'm a bit stuck with my code.
i'm programming a robot and after every position switch i want to write his current position into a ToString method so i can review this afterwards. i'm not sure that a ToString method is the correct way. maybe i need a list or an array?
I'm not asking for the solution, but some help to help me solve this issue.
Thanks for the help!
see my code below:

```
enum Richting
{
    Boven,
    Onder,
    Links,
    Rechts,
}
class Positie
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Positie (int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
class Spoor
{
    public Robot Robot { get; set; }
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return Robot.Positie.X + "-" + Robot.Positie.Y;
    }
    public void ToonSpoor()
    {
        ToString();
    }
}
class Robot
{
    public Positie Positie { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public Robot (string naam, Positie positie1)
    {
        Naam = naam;
        Positie = positie1;
    }
    public Robot (string naam)
    {
        Naam = naam;
        this.Positie = new Positie(0,0);
    }
    public Richting Richting;
    public virtual void Stap()
    {
        switch (Richting)
        {
            case Richting.Boven:    Positie.Y++; Spoor.ToString();
                break;
            case Richting.Onder:    Positie.Y--; Spoor.ToString();
                break;
            case Richting.Links:    Positie.X--; Spoor.ToString();
                break;
            case Richting.Rechts:   Positie.X++; Spoor.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
    public virtual void Stap(int aantalStappen)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < aantalStappen; i++)
        {
            switch (Richting)
            {
                case Richting.Boven:
                    Positie.Y++;
                    break;
                case Richting.Onder:
                    Positie.Y--;
                    break;
                case Richting.Links:
                    Positie.X--;
                    break;
                case Richting.Rechts:
                    Positie.X++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual void Draai()
    {
        switch (Richting)
        {
            case Richting.Boven: Richting = Richting.Rechts;
                break;
            case Richting.Onder: Richting = Richting.Links;
                break;
            case Richting.Links: Richting = Richting.Boven;
                break;
            case Richting.Rechts: Richting = Richting.Onder;
                break;
        }
    }
    public Spoor Spoor { get; set; }
}
class SpecialeRobot : Robot
{
    public SpecialeRobot (string naam) : base("")
    {
        Naam = naam;
        this.Positie = new Positie(0, 0);
    }
    public SpecialeRobot(string naam, Positie positie1) :base("")
    {
        Naam = naam;
        Positie = positie1;
    }
    public override void Stap()
    {
        switch (Richting)
        {
            case Richting.Boven:
                Positie.Y = Positie.Y + 2;
                break;
            case Richting.Onder:
                Positie.Y = Positie.Y - 2;
                break;
            case Richting.Links:
                Positie.X = Positie.X - 2;
                break;
            case Richting.Rechts:
                Positie.X = Positie.X + 2;
                break;
        }
    }
    public override void Stap(int aantalStappen)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < aantalStappen; i++)
        {
            switch (Richting)
            {
                case Richting.Boven:
                    Positie.Y++;
                    break;
                case Richting.Onder:
                    Positie.Y--;
                    break;
                case Richting.Links:
                    Positie.X--;
                    break;
                case Richting.Rechts:
                    Positie.X++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public override void Draai()
    {
        switch (Richting)
        {
            case Richting.Boven:
                Richting = Richting.Rechts;
                break;
            case Richting.Onder:
                Richting = Richting.Links;
                break;
            case Richting.Links:
                Richting = Richting.Boven;
                break;
            case Richting.Rechts:
                Richting = Richting.Onder;
                break;
        }
    }
}
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Aanmaken van een positie-object
        Positie positie1 = new Positie(2, 3);
        // Aanmaken van een robot
        Console.WriteLine("1 ------------------------------------------");
        Robot robot1 = new Robot("Bart", positie1);
        // ----controles uitvoeren
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Naam == "Bart");
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Positie.X == 2);
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Positie.Y == 3);
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Richting == Richting.Boven);
        Console.WriteLine("11 ------------------------------------------");
        robot1.Stap();
        robot1.Stap();
        robot1.Stap();
        robot1.Spoor.ToonSpoor();       // 2 - 3 -> 2 - 4 -> 2 - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

ToString is perfectly ok for your case. But, it's better to override it instead of hiding using the 'new' keyword. So it's better to write:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Robot.Positie.X + "-" + Robot.Positie.Y;
}
```

Also you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278049/why-when-would-it-be-appropriate-to-override-tostring) question that might be useful.

Comment: thanks, but when i do this (also with new) i get a error message that i need to use the new keyword to create a instance of an object. i don't have an idea where i need to do this

Comment: Well of course you need to instantiate your `Spoor` class. That should be done where you want to consume the class. Classes only work with information finally you have to have another place to show the output to the user which is where you create an instance of `Spoor` and use it's `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to maintain a log of positions that the robot visited - that is, positions after each call of `Robot.Stap()`

One way to achieve this is by adding the list of visited positions such as

`private List<Positie> visitedPositions;`

to the `Robot` class and adding a record of robot's current position after each call of `Robot.Stap()`

Then you can get the information about robot's path by outputting the contents of this list.

```
class Robot
{
    private List<Positie> visitedPositions = new List<Positie>();
    public void PrintPositions () {
        foreach (var pos in visitedPositions) {
            Console.WriteLine (pos.X + " " + pos.Y);
        }
    }
    ...

    public virtual void Stap()
    {
        switch (Richting)
        {
            case Richting.Boven:    Positie.Y++;
            break;
            case Richting.Onder:    Positie.Y--;
            break;
            case Richting.Links:    Positie.X--;
            break;
            case Richting.Rechts:   Positie.X++;
            break;
        }
        visitedPositions.Add (new Positie (Positie.X, Positie.Y));

    }
    public virtual void Stap(int aantalStappen)
    {
        ...
        visitedPositions.Add (new Positie (Positie.X, Positie.Y));
    }

}

class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        Robot robot1;
        ...

        robot1.Stap ();
        robot1.PrintPositions ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Than i have to change the program. I want to keep the intelligence into the classes and not outside of it.

Comment: I added some outlines of the code, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help!!

Answer (score -1):

Why not add a private variable inside your `Program` class and use your class `Positie`?

You can add this anywhere inside your `Program`
    private Positie position;

Then you can set `position` it in your `Program` something like:

```
class Program 
{
    private Positie position;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Aanmaken van een positie-object
        Positie positie1 = new Positie(2, 3);
        // Aanmaken van een robot
        Console.WriteLine("1 ------------------------------------------");
        Robot robot1 = new Robot("Bart", positie1);
        // ----controles uitvoeren
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Naam == "Bart");
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Positie.X == 2);
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Positie.Y == 3);
        Console.WriteLine(robot1.Richting == Richting.Boven);
        Console.WriteLine("11 ------------------------------------------");
        robot1.Stap();
        position = robot1.Positie; // <- this line
        robot1.Stap();
        robot1.Stap();
        robot1.Spoor.ToonSpoor();       // 2 - 3 -> 2 - 4 -> 2 - 5
```

therefore, to access your private variable you can directly call `position`

```
Console.WriteLine(position.X);
Console.WriteLine(position.Y);
Console.WriteLine("Robot position: (" + position.X.Tostring() + "," + position.X.Tostring() + ")");
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that declaring the variable `position` should be inside `Program`

Comment: I want to stay away from the program. This is only for testing.
The intelligence should be in the classes.